# How to edit mp3 artists property in the terminal

Tags: command-line, id3

So I know I can edit the mp3 song properties in rhythmbox. However, it very time consuming to do this via the GTK+ interface. So I was hoping there was a way to do it in the terminal. I look at the rhythmbox --help, however I don’t see a any options that could help. Does anyone know how I can do this in the terminal. Third party software is an acceptable answer in my book.

Comment: No, i was hoping to add artists tags, not images and stuff.

Comment: How is that different from `eyeD3 --artist=STRING my_file.mp3`?

Comment: O i just add an artists argument. Cool thanks bro